# sidenotes package : error in figure alignment

Tags: sidenotes

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}



\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=42pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt}
%


\begin{document}

%
\begin{marginfigure}%
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{A small rectangle put in the margin.\label{rectangle}}%
\end{marginfigure}%
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
%\centering
    \includegraphics[height=180pt,width=350pt]{example-image-c}%
    \caption{An even larger rectangle. This is the widest figure option. Both, the text as well as the margin width are used for the diagram.}
    \label{rectangle3}
\end{figure*}
%
\clearpage
%
\begin{marginfigure}%
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{A small rectangle put in the margin.\label{rectangle2}}%
\end{marginfigure}%
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
%\centering
    \includegraphics[height=180pt,width=350pt]{example-image-c}%
    \caption{An even larger rectangle. This is the widest figure option. Both, the text as well as the margin width are used for the diagram.}
    \label{rectangle31}
\end{figure*}
%
\end{document}
```

Error in second page
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are a victim of `end of line space`. Put a `%` after `[htbp]`

```
\begin{figure*}[htbp]%
%\centering
    \includegraphics[height=180pt,width=350pt]{example-image-c}%
    \caption{An even larger rectangle. This is the widest figure option. Both, the text as well as the margin width are used for the diagram.}
    \label{rectangle31}
\end{figure*}%
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=42pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt}
%


\begin{document}

%
\begin{marginfigure}%
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{A small rectangle put in the margin.\label{rectangle}}%
\end{marginfigure}%
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
%\centering
    \includegraphics[height=180pt,width=350pt]{example-image-c}%
    \caption{An even larger rectangle. This is the widest figure option. Both, the text as well as the margin width are used for the diagram.}
    \label{rectangle3}
\end{figure*}
%
\clearpage
%
\begin{marginfigure}%
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{A small rectangle put in the margin.\label{rectangle2}}%
\end{marginfigure}%
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{figure*}[htbp]%
%\centering
    \includegraphics[height=180pt,width=350pt]{example-image-c}%
    \caption{An even larger rectangle. This is the widest figure option. Both, the text as well as the margin width are used for the diagram.}
    \label{rectangle31}
\end{figure*}%
%
\end{document}
```

[image]